# Fitting an ImageView into a TreeTableCell

Tags: javafx, treetableview, jfoenix

I am using a `JFXTreeTableView` which has a column which displays images. The column is constucted like this:

```
JFXTreeTableColumn<MyLog, ImageView> statusColumn = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Status");
statusColumn.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<MyLog, ImageView> param) -> {
    return param.getValue().getValue().statusImage;
});
```

The class `MyLog` looks like this:

```
public class MyLog extends RecursiveTreeObject<MyLog> {


    // more properties...
    public ObjectProperty<ImageView> statusImage = new SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>();

    public MyLog(String imagePath)
    {
        statusImage.set(new ImageView(new Image(MyProject.class.getResourceAsStream(imagePath))));
    }
}
```

The image I am trying to display is this one:

[image]

However, the image is not fitting into the cell correctly. This is how the table looks:

[image]

How can I make the image fit into the cell without modifing the image itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seperate the data you want to display (`Image`) and the way it's displayed (`ImageView`).

This is done by modifying `MyLog`'s `statusImage` property to contain type `Image` and using a `cellFactory` that returns `TreeTableCell`s that use `ImageView`s to display the images.

```
public class MyLog extends RecursiveTreeObject<MyLog> {

    // more properties...

    public final ObjectProperty<Image> statusImage;

    public MyLog(String imagePath) {
        this(new Image(MyProject.class.getResourceAsStream(imagePath)));
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for passing Image objects.
     * (Could be helpful to reuse Images to reduce the footprint.)
     */
    public MyLog(Image statusImage) {
        this.statusImage = new SimpleObjectProperty(statusImage);
    }

}
```

```
statusColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new JFXTreeTableCell<MyLog, Image>() {

    private final ImageView imageView;

    {
        imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(20);
        imageView.setFitHeight(20);
        setGraphic(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Image item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        imageView.setImage(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but updateItem function returns every item as null but empty parameter is false, any idea?

Comment: ok, for someone who has same error as me, i forgot to create this line `        imageCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().image);
`